# Number of products that falls into 'more than 4 days' and 'less than 4 days'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn how to add a sum function in my case statement. That calculates the number of products that falls into either 'more than 4 days' or 'less than 4 days'. I'm using adventureworks2014 in Microsoft sql. Here my query below.

```
USE AdventureWorks2014;

GO

SELECT

CASE 

WHEN DAYSTOMANUFACTURE < = 4 THEN  'LESS THAN 4 DAYS'

ELSE 'MORE THAN 4 DAYS'

END AS TIMEFRAME, 

ProductID,NAME

FROM PRODUCTION.PRODUCT  

ORDER BY TIMEFRAME
```

Comment: What exactly you want to sum ? Add that column name

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DAYSTOMANUFACTURE < = 4 THEN  'LESS THAN 4 DAYS'
             ELSE 'MORE THAN 4 DAYS'
        END) AS TIMEFRAME, 
       COUNT(*) as NumProducts
FROM PRODUCTION.PRODUCT  
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN DAYSTOMANUFACTURE < = 4 THEN  'LESS THAN 4 DAYS'
               ELSE 'MORE THAN 4 DAYS'
          END);
```